# How to move the "camera" on mouse drag in OpenGL where the "camera" is always aiming at the object?

Tags: opengl, glut, glu

Im new to OpenGL and GL,GLU,GLUT seems to be deprecated for a long time but there is an homework assignment and im figuring out how to move the camera to different angles but the camera will always be pointing at the object.

I've searched through internet and stackoverflow but all seems to be using `glutMainLoop();` but in my case, i'm using a `while()` loop in my `WinMain` where the loop keeps on calling `display()`. So I'm trying out some random code i got from the internet where it calls the `glutMouseFunc(mouse)` before the `glutMainLoop();` and i think it is simlar to my `while()` loop but it doesn't work.

Can someone explain why?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <gl/GLUT.h>

#define WINDOW_TITLE "OpenGL Window"


LRESULT WINAPI WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE) PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

bool initPixelFormat(HDC hdc)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));

    pfd.cAlphaBits = 8;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 24;
    pfd.cStencilBits = 0;

    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;

    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;

    // choose pixel format returns the number most similar pixel format available
    int n = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);

    // set pixel format returns whether it sucessfully set the pixel format
    if (SetPixelFormat(hdc, n, &pfd))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
void spinDisplay(void)
{
    spin = spin + 2.0;
    if (spin > 360.0)
        spin = spin - 360.0;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    switch (button) {
    case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            glutIdleFunc(spinDisplay);
        break;
    case GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            glutIdleFunc(NULL);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glutSolidCube(0.2);
    
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wc.lpszClassName = WINDOW_TITLE;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) return false;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE, WINDOW_TITLE, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 600,
        NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);

    //--------------------------------
    //  Initialize window for OpenGL
    //--------------------------------

    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

    //  initialize pixel format for the window
    initPixelFormat(hdc);

    //  get an openGL context
    HGLRC hglrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);

    //  make context current
    if (!wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hglrc)) return false;

    //--------------------------------
    //  End initialization
    //--------------------------------

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(msg));

    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) break;

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        glutMouseFunc(mouse);
        display();

        SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }

    UnregisterClass(WINDOW_TITLE, wc.hInstance);

    return true;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why do you mix Windows API and GLUT?

Comment: @Rabbid76 they can't be used together? Sorry im new

Comment: I don't think they can be. What happens when you move the mouse? Windows calls your window procedure with WM_MOUSEMOVE, because it's your window, not GLUT's window. GLUT never sees the message so it doesn't know the mouse moved!

Comment: to implement an orbit camera, simply track your camera position and object position. Then you can point the camera along `objectPosVector - cameraPosVector` positioned at `cameraPosVector`